# Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a group $G$ and assume $|G : H| < +\infty$. Show that $|K : K \cap H| \le |G : H|.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a group $G$ and assume $|G : H| < +\infty$. Show that $|K : K \cap H| \le |G : H|.$

To show this I'm making a map from $K/K\cap H\to G/H$ with $K/K \cap H=\{(K\cap H)a: a\in K\}$ and $\{(Hb)a: b\to G\}$ which we sees get $(K\cap H)a\to Ha$.

I want to show this map is well defined and it's is one to one but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Can't you just apply the appropriate (second?) isomorphism theorem, as $KH$ has finite index in $G$, and indeed $|G:KH|\leq|G:H|$?

Comment: No, isomorphism theorems involve normal subgroups, which is not provided in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the map is well-defined, you have to deal with the possibility of $(K \cap H)a$ being represented in a different way. Specifically, if $a_1$ and $a_2$ belong to the same coset $(K \cap H)a$ in $K$ (i.e. $(K \cap H)a_1 = (K \cap H)a_1$), then they both produce the same coset under this map (i.e. $Ha_1 = Ha_2$).

Now, if $(k \cap H)a_1 = (k \cap H)a_1$, then there exists some $x \in K \cap H$ such that $a_1 = xa_2$. But then $x \in H$, so
$$Ha_2 = H(xa_1) = (Hx)a_1 = Ha_1.$$

That is, the map is well-defined.

To show it is one-to-one, assume we have two cosets of $H \cap K$ in $K$ that map to the same coset of $H$ in $K$. That is, suppose we have $a_1, a_2 \in K$ such that $a_1H = a_2 H$. But then, this means that $a_1a_2^{-1} \in H$. Since $a_1, a_2 \in K$, a subgroup, this means that $a_1a_2^{-1} \in H \cap K$. This also implies that $a_1(H \cap K) = a_2(H \cap K)$, i.e. the map is one-to-one.